# Как продуктивно создавать оболочки совместимости (shims), для .Net Core, Framework, Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .netcore2.0, .net-standard

Как продуктивно создавать оболочки совместимости (shims), для `.Net` `Core`, `Framework`, `Standard`?

*Версии:* `Framework 4.6.1`; `Core 2.0`; `Standard 2.0`.

Например, интересуют следующие 3 штуки, для использования между `.net core`, `.net standard` и `.net framework`:

`System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`, `System.ComponentModel.ItemPropertyInfo.Descriptor`, даже 
`System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem`.

На самом деле, похоже, что таких оболочек нужно намного больше. Безусловно, их можно создавать вручную. Но может быть есть более продуктивный способ, чтобы избежать механической работы?

---

**Пояснение задачи на грубом примере, если делать вручную:**

Например, для `Core 2.0` не реализован `Dispatcher`.

Делается абстрактная оболочка / интерфейс / фасад, :

```
public enum DispatcherShimPriority
{
    Background
    //...
}

public interface DispaicherShim
{
    void Invoke(Action action, DispatcherShimPriority prio);
    void BeginInvoke(Action action, DispatcherShimPriority, prio);
}
```

Далее 2 реализации:

```
public class DispatcherCore: DispaicherShim;
//здесь по началу можно просто вызывать Action
```

и

```
public class DispatcherFramework: DispaicherShim;
//здесь используется реальный Dispatcher внутри
```

Далее делается какой-то мультинацеленный класс-активатор, например, `Shims`, в котором:

```
public static DispaicherShim CreateDispatcher()
{
#if NETCOREAPP2_0
    return new DispatcherCore();
#else
    return new DispatcherFramework();
#endif       
}
```

Таким образом, получается оболочка, которую можно использовать как в Framework-овских, так и в Core-овских приложениях.

Создание таких оболочек требует много механической работы. Интуитивно мне кажется, что эту работу проделывать не обязательно, что есть уже готовые решения...

---

Про `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` pack в курсе. Имею ввиду создание оболочек для элементов, не покрывающихся данным пакетом.

Про `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility.Shims` слышал, но подозреваю, что там нет оболочек для элементов, не покрывающихся самим пакетом.

---

Общая задача состоит в том, чтобы основную часть WPF приложения перевести на кор под потенциальный web-client (оставляя работающий WPF), при том, что многие элементы .net framework основной части не переводятся на кор.

Comment: Мне кажется, смотреть надо каждый такой класс отдельно. В диспатчере просто нет смысла, т.к. UI либ в netcore сейчас нет целиком, что откуда куда и зачем вы собрались пробрасывать то?

Comment: @Monk, На счет "что откуда куда и зачем вы собрались пробрасывать": ну может быть когда-нибудь через сокеты в `Asp.Net Core` приложении будет, например, пробрасываться изменение прогресс бара или другие изменения UI. Но о конкретике пока рано говорить. Пока просто вызов `Action`-а. И `Dispatcher` - это только один из многих примеров....

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203905/creating-a-compatibility-shim-for-exampleclass-to-be-targeted-both-to-net-frame

Comment: Просто вы в посте пишите, что ищете готовые решения. Но готовые решения не нужны никому (всмысле их никто не пишет), пока нет реальной задачи. Из ваших в заголовке - минимум диспатчер и менюитем реализованы только в одном месте и тащить их больше неоткуда. Т.е. у них только одна реализация в текущем мире и пилить обертку вроде незачем. Какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: @Monk - ну чтобы не сильно менять код всего приложения (недостаточно времени и сложно разобраться), а просто заменять вызов класса на вызов обертки, а внутри обертки чтобы выбирался класс в зависимости от платформы, чтобы в итоге логика приложения работала и под кор и под фреймворк.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

К этому моменту нашел, по крайней мере, удовлетворяющие способы создания оболочек совместимости. Может есть более продуктивные методы.

Спасибо [Firda](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52292/firda) из Чехии. [Вот его ответ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203943/99102)

## 1) В принципе достаточно простой generic оболочки

```
public abstract class Shim<TImpl>
{
    internal TImpl It { get; }
    protected Shim(TImpl it) { It = it; }
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```
public class DispatcherPriorityShim : Shim<
#if NETFULL
    DispatcherPriority
#elif NETCORE
    string
#endif
>
{
    public DispatcherPriorityShim(string it)
#if NETFULL
        : base((DispatcherPriority)Enum.Parse(typeof(DispatcherPriority), it))
#elif NETCORE
        : base(it)
#endif
    { }
}
```

## 1.a) Visual Studio [snippets](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-custom-code-snippet-in-visual-studio-2015/)

**drv**

```
#if NETFULL

#elif NETCORE

#endif
```

**shimenum**

```
namespace PortabilityLibrary.Shims
{
  public class $enumname$Shim : Shim<
#if NETFULL
    $enumname$
#elif NETCORE
    string
#endif
>
  {
        public $enumname$Shim(string it)
#if NETFULL
        : base(($enumname$)Enum.Parse(typeof($enumname$), it))
#elif NETCORE
          : base(it)
#endif
        { }
  }
}
```

**shimsnip**

```
namespace PortabilityLibrary.Shims
{
  public class $classname$Shim : Shim<
#if NETFULL
    $classname$
#elif NETCORE
    $classname$
//NullObject
#endif
>
  {
        public $classname$Shim()
#if NETFULL
        : base(new $classname$())
#elif NETCORE
        : base(new $classname$())
    //: base(new NullObject())
#endif
        {}
  }
}
```

**shimmeth**

```
        public void $methodname$()
        {
#if NETFULL
        It.$methodname$();
#elif NETCORE
        It.$methodname$();
        //throw new ShimException();
#endif
        }
```

**shimprop** - аналогично, пока не сделал

## 1.b) Пояснение на счет `NETCORE` и `NETFULL`

Sdk-style `.csproj` file to make clear about `NETFULL` and `NETCORE`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup><TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks></PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;</DefineConstants></PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <DefineConstants>NETFULL;</DefineConstants></PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

---

## 2) Более продвинутый вариант позволяющий наследственность

```
public interface IShimOne
{
    void MethodOne();
}
public interface IShimTwo: IShimOne
{
    void MethodTwo();
}

class One: RealOne, IShimOne {}
class Two: RealTwo, IShimTwo {}
public static class ShimFactory
{
    public static IShimOne CreateOne() { return new One(); }
    public static IShimTwo CreateTwo() { return new Two(); }
}
```

## 2.a) Объекты

```
public class WrapperOne
{
    protected IShimOne It { get; }
    protected WrapperOne(IShimOne it) { It = it; }
    public WrapperOne() { It = ShimFactory.CreateOne(); }
    public void MethodOne() { It.MethodOne(); }
}
public class WrapperTwo: WrapperOne
{
    protected new IShimTwo It => (IShimTwo)base.It;
    protected WrapperTwo(IShimTwo it): base(it) {}
    public WrapperTwo(): base(ShimFactory.CreateTwo()) {}
    public void MethodTwo() { It.MethodTwo(); }
```

---

## 3) Готовые "двойники" для GUI контролов ([Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto))

(вообще, Eto.Forms имеет более широкое применение - они сами по себе уже оболочки)

```
//Не до конца сделано, просто чтобы показать идею:

#if NETFULL
using System.Windows.Controls;
#elif NETCORE
using Eto.Forms;
#endif

namespace PortabilityLibrary.Shims
{
    public class MenuItemShim : Shim<
#if NETFULL
    MenuItem
#elif NETCORE
    MenuItem
#endif
    >
    {
        public MenuItemShim(EventHandler<EventArgs> dlg)
#if NETFULL
        : base(new MenuItem(/*not implemented*/))
#elif NETCORE
        : base(new ButtonMenuItem(dlg))
#endif
        { }
    }
}
```